# PHP / MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

After days of failing I hope that someone more skilled can help me with a solution.

I have two tables, one containing stocks and the other stock values. Please, you do not have to comment on field types etc as this is not a production development, I am only trying to get a grasp on join and mysql alias.

```
-- Stocks table:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stocks`;
CREATE TABLE `stocks` (
  `stock_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stock_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stock_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- Sample records:

INSERT INTO `stocks` VALUES ('1', 'HighTech');
INSERT INTO `stocks` VALUES ('2', 'NanoTech');
INSERT INTO `stocks` VALUES ('3', 'DotCom');
INSERT INTO `stocks` VALUES ('4', 'NewBiz');


-- Values table:
```

> ```
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vals`;
> CREATE TABLE `values` (
>   `vals_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `stock_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `stock_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`vals_id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> ```

```
-- Sample records:

INSERT INTO `vals` VALUES ('1', '1', '50');
INSERT INTO `vals` VALUES ('2', '1', '700');
INSERT INTO `vals` VALUES ('3', '1', '540');
INSERT INTO `vals` VALUES ('4', '3', '15');
INSERT INTO `vals` VALUES ('5', '3', '44');
INSERT INTO `vals` VALUES ('6', '1', '60');
INSERT INTO `vals` VALUES ('7', '2', '10');
INSERT INTO `vals` VALUES ('8', '3', '53');
```

There could be 100s of stocks and 1000s of value records.

What I want to do is to print each stock together with a single (latest) stock value. 
For stock number 3 I want to echo "DotCom" and the latest value "53", none of the others values.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @JohnConde: [should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/)

Comment: I am sorry for the lack of information, I was on my mobile phone. I will update the post tomorrow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yeah , your table name values creating problem here , try to change it to someother name like vals or something.it would works/

here it is

```
 SELECT * FROM stocks S JOIN vals V ON V.vals_id = ( SELECT MAX(vals_id) FROM vals Va WHERE Va.stock_id = S.stock_id )
```

Comment: I am unable to implement until tomorrow, but this seems to be a proper solution. Thank you very much user3515379! :)

Comment: Back at my computer I tried your code today. It is somewhat similar to what I have tried earlier, and unfortunately with the same (lack of) results. It looks like my xampp server does not approve of using table alias like "..stocks as s.." Really annoying.

Comment: You should use without alias than.

Comment: Believe me, I have tried. Can you see anything wrong here?
SELECT stocks.stock_name, values.stock_value
FROM stocks
INNER JOIN values
ON values.stock_id = stocks.stock_id
ORDER BY stocks.stock_id DESC

Comment: "values", a reserved word.. Thank you so much for pointing that out, hours waisted learning that the hard way ;) Now I get a list of stocks and their corresponding values (plural). I tried with GROUP BY stocs.stock_id to get only the single newest value, I received the oldest.. Do you have one final tip for me? :)

Comment: Okay,you need to loop through the result to get all the rows `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
//Do stuff 
}`

Comment: $result contains 8 rows (see sample records above). Is there no way to use LIMIT 1 on vals or something in order to have $result contain only the three newest values?

Comment: Hmmm , try this `select stocks.stock_name,vals.stock_value  from stocks , vals 
where (stocks.stock_id , vals.stock_value) in 
(select vals.stock_id , max(vals.stock_value) from vals group by vals.stock_id)
 order by vals.stock_id desc
`

Comment: Never been closer! The results are now showing only one value for each stock, but it's the highest value and not necessarily the latest one (the one with the highest vals_id) Your query is a bit too complex for me to understand right now, hopefully I will understand it and be able to edit it tomorrow. If you feel like checking it again please feel free, if not thank you so much for your effort with this =D

Comment: Hi again. Following  an article I made the following solution which seems to work 100 %

Comment: SELECT  *
FROM    stocks S
JOIN    vals V
ON      V.vals_id = 
        (
            SELECT  MAX(vals_id)
            FROM    vals Va
            WHERE   Va.stock_id = S.stock_id
        )